# How to inject downgraded Angular service into an AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, dependency-injection, ng-upgrade

I have been following the guide [here](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/07/14/directly-upgrading-from-angularjs-1-x-to-angular-by-skipping-preparation.aspx) for upgrading an angularjs project.

However, the code base I really want to upgrade already has ts classes for a majority of services so I followed the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-the-phone-service) that replaces the angularjs phone service with a ts class.  So now I have a ts class for the phone service, but when I run the application with `ng serve` the phone service is an unknown provider.

- I have tried adding `"types": ["angular"]` to my tsconfig.
- I have tried declaring angular in the service file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { IPhoneData } from "../../interfaces/IPhoneData";

// angular does not get resolved during compilation this way
// declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

// Phone is an unknown provider this way
declare var angular: any;

import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Injectable()
export class Phone {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  query(): Observable<IPhoneData[]> {
    return this.http.get<IPhoneData[]>(`phones/phones.json`);
  }
  get(id: string): Observable<IPhoneData> {
    return this.http.get<IPhoneData>(`phones/${id}.json`);
  }
}

angular.module('core.phone')
  .factory('phone', downgradeInjectable(Phone));
```

How can I get the phone service ts class injected into an angularjs component?  Link to [my repo](https://github.com/dentudave/upgradeNoPrep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line I lost the case of the 'Phone' factory, it should have been like below (also the Observables should have been promises).

```
export class Phone {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  query(): Promise<IPhoneData[]> {
    return this.http.get<IPhoneData[]>(`phones/phones.json`).toPromise();
  }
  get(id: string): Promise<IPhoneData> {
    return this.http.get<IPhoneData>(`phones/${id}.json`).toPromise();
  }
}

angular.module('core.phone')
  .factory('Phone', downgradeInjectable(Phone));
```